# XPath testing text in child elements?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I have HTML with a table-like format (not `<table>`).  I need to check if the given `row` has all the values.

```
...
<div id="rows">
  <div class="row">
    <p>Java</p>
    <p>Ruby</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <p>HTML</p>
    <p>Ruby</p>
  </div>
</div>
...
```

How do I check using xpath if this has `Java AND Ruby` within a single `row`?

I tried `//p[text()='Java' and text()='Ruby']` but didn't quite work.  Also tried  `//div[@id='rows']//p[contains(text(),'Java') and contains(text(),'Ruby')]`

Answer (score 1):

Try using below `xpath` :-

```
//div[normalize-space(.) = 'Java Ruby']
```

or

```
//div[@class = 'row' and contains(.,'Java') and contains(.,'Ruby')]
```

or If you want `div` with id `rows` with multiple contains try as :-

```
//div[@id= 'rows' and contains(.,'Java') and contains(.,'Ruby')]
```

Answer (score 1):

This XPath,

```
//div[@class='row' and p='Java' and p='Ruby']
```

will select all `div/@class='row'` elements with `Java` and `Ruby` string values among the `p` children.